# To friend vs. to befriend

Tags: meaning, differences

I overheard a mother correct her child who said something to the effect of

> There was a new kid in my class today and I friended him.

The mother said *befriended* and I was inclined to mentally agree (given the kid was maybe six or seven, it's unlikely that he was referring to social networking).

However, with a little Googling, I discovered an article from *The Atlantic* which suggests that ['Friend,' as a Verb, Is 800 Years Old](http://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2013/07/friend-as-a-verb-is-800-years-old/278109/).

> - "Make no purses, for to friend yourself therewith." -- the Guide for Anchoresses, early 13th century
> - "And after soon friended were the King David of Scotland and Stephen, king then of England." -- Andrew of Wyntoun, *Chronicles*, c. 1425

This [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/26019/44117) regarding the *be* prefix offers:

> The general form is:
>
> ```
>    be + [quality]
> ```
>
> and the corresponding meaning is:
>
> ```
>  to turn into + [quality].
> ```

So, I guess my question, then, is what is the difference between the verbs to friend and to befriend? Was the kid right?

Comment: The boy befriended the new kid.  The two children were then friended.  (?)

Comment: I immediately imagine both children on Facebook, where *friending* is indeed the correct verb...

Comment: @PatrickM disheartening, but true.

Comment: Going back somewhat more than a century -- poem LXII of  A.E. Housman's "A Shropshire Lad" is pretty famous -- it's the one that begins with "Terence, this is stupid stuff" and has the oft-quoted couplet "And malt does more than Milton can/To justify God's ways to man". At one point, the poet promises that if you should become as miserable as he is, "And I will friend you, if I may/In the dark and cloudy day." I can't recommend this splendid poem enough!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Friend* as a verb is very old, but its use is now limited to adding someone to a list of social network contacts. *Befriend* doesn’t necessarily mean ‘make a friend of’. It is typically used when a person offers support to someone in difficulties, rather like the good Samaritan.

If you’re describing the establishment of a close, but not sexual or romantic, relationship, you have to say that two people are, or have become, friends.