# Why is it "behead" and not "dehead"?

Tags: word-choice, etymology, prefixes

The **be-** prefix in **behead** doesn't seem to match similar words like *become*, *besmirch*, or *befuddle*. Of course, the same prefix could serve different roles depending on the word. What role is **be-** serving here, and are there any other English words that use the prefix in this way?

Comment: Related: [How does the “be-” prefix change the words to which it is applied? How did it come about?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25951/how-does-the-be-prefix-change-the-words-to-which-it-is-applied-how-did-it-co)

Comment: @ermanen: Not only related. That question and its answers seems to cover this one. Shouldn't this be closed as a dup?

Comment: @Drew Are you sure? I think the answer to this question is the first sentence of my answer, which I don’t see how to infer from that question.

Comment: @tchrist: OK, that adds to what is on the other page, by specifically addressing the *de-* alternative. It doesn't deal with *Why be-?* in a satisfying way, however, and that is answered over there. Answering *Why be-?* with *Because we already had de-* is leaves something to be desired (it is true, but a bit of a copout). It leaves out *Then why not foo- or wup- instead of de-?* Anyway, I see your point as to why to keep this as another question.

Comment: @Drew There is also the minor issue that the accepted (and very upvoted!) answer in the other is _wrong_ and gives a completely anachronistic and incorrect etymology for the _be-_ prefix. Also, that question does not deal with the last bit of this one: what other words use _be-_ in this rare, privative sense. (Incidentally, “Why not _be-_? Because we already had _de-_” is not what tchrist’s answer says at all. It says, “Why not _dehead_? Because we already had _behead_.”)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet: You put what I said backward. I wrote about answering *Why be-?* with *Because de-*, not answering *Why* ***not*** *be-?* with *Because de-*. And yes, I meant what you said in your last sentence - I was trying to save comment space by not repeating *dehead* & *behead*.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yeah, that answer has a very weird notion of *be-*'s origins and connections. The first paragraph of the OED’s rather lengthy *be-* entry is much more interesting — and completely different from anything in that answer.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

We didn’t use *de-head* be­cause we al­ready had a verb *be­head* by the time
we start­ed us­ing *de-* to cre­ate verbs: *be­head* was a verb in Old English,
*be­héaf­di­an*.

So *be­head* was al­ready used long be­fore the *de-* pri­va­tive pre­fix came to
be used pro­duc­tive­ly in English. That didn’t hap­pen un­til Modern English
with a few pro­duc­tive ex­am­ples in the 17ᵗʰ cen­tu­ry but most com­ing from the
19ᵗʰ cen­tu­ry or af­ter.  As Ja­nus men­tions in com­ments, the *de-* word
mean­ing the same thing, *de­cap­i­tate*, was im­port­ed in full with the *de-*
al­ready there, from Latin via French, in the 17ᵗʰ cen­tu­ry.

There are many dif­fer­ent pos­si­ble sens­es of *be-* in verbs; the OED lists
six dif­fer­ent pri­ma­ry sens­es with sub­sens­es.  This here in *be­head* is one
of the rar­er ones. Un­der *be-* sense 6c, it says that this pri­va­tive sense
of *be-* used to cre­ate *be­head* is an an­cient sense that means *be­reave
of*:

> 6. Form­ing trans. verbs on sub­stan­tives used in an in­stru­men­tal re­la­tion; the pri­ma­ry idea be­ing;
>
>    - **a.** To sur­round, cov­er, or be­daub with, as in *be­cloud*, to put clouds about, cov­er with clouds, *be­dew*. Thence, by ex­ten­sion,
>    - **b.** To af­fect with in any way, as in *be­night, be­guile, be­friend*. In both sets there is of­ten an ac­com­pa­ny­ing no­tion of ‘thor­ough­ly, ex­ces­sive­ly,’ as in 2.
>    - **c.** An an­cient ap­pli­ca­tion, no longer in liv­ing use, was to ex­press the sense of ‘be­reave of,’ as in ***be­head***, *be­limb*, etc., q.v. Cf. 3, above.

Al­though 6a and 6b are still pro­duc­tive, 6c no longer is so in the liv­ing
lan­guage. Another Old English verb formed us­ing 6c was
[*belandian*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/beland#English), mean­ing to
de­prive of one’s land. How­ev­er, this verb did not sur­vive in­to Modern English.

#### El destierro

Apro­pos de na­da, the Span­ish equiv­a­lent of the ob­so­lete verb *be­land* still very much
ex­ists in the verb *des­te­rrar*, which com­bines the pri­va­tive *des‑* 
pre­fix with the noun *tie­rra* mean­ing land then puts that in­to an 
in­fini­tive verb form.  This is nor­mal­ly trans­lat­ed as “ex­ile” in
English, but some­time as “ex­pel” or as a noun “ex­pul­sion”. There is
al­so a sub­stan­tive ver­sion, *destier­ro*, is fa­mous­ly found in
[“Can­tar del
des­tie­rro”](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantar_de_mio_Cid#Primer_cantar._Cantar_del_destierro_(vv._1%E2%80%931084)),
which is the ti­tle of the first can­to from that most an­cient of
Cas­til­ian epic po­ems, *El Can­tar de Mio Cid*.

Tru­ly, el Cid was **be­land­ed** of his lands by the King.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the *de-* prefix didn't come into English until after that Old English *beheafdian*, so there was no point where it could have gone either way between *dehead* and *behead*.

Comment: @JonHanna That’s a good point: the productive, privative sense of *de-* in English is actually quite new as these things are measured. (Things imported wholesale from Latin don’t count, of course.)

Comment: Even much of the wholesale importing is newer than *beheafdian*.

Comment: @JonHanna Yes of course, but I still don’t count wholesales as productive uses. :)

Comment: Perhaps also worth noting that the wholesale import of the same procedure does in fact use _de-_, though with the accompanying Latin word for ‘head’: _decapitate_ (from Latin _capit-_ ‘head’).

Comment: The expression "to bereave of one's head" is wonderfully expressive. I love archaic English.

Comment: So "to castrate" could be also expressed as "to bepenis".

Comment: @eltomito You mean *bepintel* —or more specifically, *beballock*. You can almost never derive a new English word by applying a Germanic prefix to a Latin base word, with only a few highly productive, well-known exceptions. Old English used *pintel* for Latin *penis*, and there are no surviving privative uses of *be‑* that attached to anything but a word descended from Old English such as *land, limb, head*. In any case this ancient privative prefix is “no longer in living use” per the OED, and so it it is no longer productive…outside in-jokes amongst painfully erudite philologists. 

Answer (score 8):

From [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/be-):be- (rare or no longer productive) Off, away, over, across

becut, bedeal, betake, bego, behead, belimb, beland, benim, bereave, besleeve, betrunk

Answer (score 5):

Behead.

From Saxon Be-=('to') and heawian=hew=cut off.
The original is "Beheawon heafde" to cut off the head.

From "Beheawon heafde" to "Beheawonheafde" to "Beheafde" to  "Behead". ( somewhere through the ages some lexicographer did away with the double 'hea' and further surgery carried out resulted to "Beheafde" and later "Behead".)

Be- [Germanic 'be'] is often used as a prefix. 
When prefixed to verbs, be- frequently expresses an active signification, as behabban to surround; begangan to perform or dispatch, &c. 
Sometimes be- prefixed indicates no perceptible variation in the sense ; as belifan to be 
remaining, or over and above, begyrdan to begird or gird, as in sprengan and bespren- 
gan to sprinkle, or besprinkle.

(1726 English Etymology Dictionary) (Anglo-Saxon Dictionary 1888)

Answer (score -6):

This type of be- denoting separation ( only in certain older verbs) is in my view connected with German ab- (one meaning can be separation) and Latin ab-. Somehow the b has changed its position from after the vowel to before the vowel. This can be explained as metathesis or a right-left phenomenon.

Comment: No, it’s not. It’s simply one of many, many meanings _by_ had already in Old English, especially when used as a preverb. The English equivalent to _ab_ never had an actual [b] to begin with, only a [β], which very early on became a [v]. The equivalent preverb is _of-_, which has fallen out of use since Middle English, where it was generally replaced with _off-_ in those verbs that survived in the language. German also has these privative senses of _be-_ here and there, such as _berauben_, which is a precise equivalent to _bereave_.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet bereave (and bereft) seem redundant, since reaving is depriving someone of something.

Comment: I take it that to deprive is related to Latin privare + Abl and that privare belongs to the word family rapere/ripere and that p- of privare is a remainder of ab-  in the sense of "away+to take"just as a robber does.

Comment: English *prive, deprive, privative, privacy, private* all come from Latin *privus* meaning single, individual, private, peculiar, deprived. I don't guess there’s any *p-* element there to further decompose, but I’ll let @JanusBahsJacquet do any further tracing.

Comment: There are a lot of German words using the Be- prefix as well, including "Behnehmen" which means "Behaviour".  I wonder if the Be- prefix has similar Saxon roots to the old English Be- prefix.