# Origin of "Bedazzle"

Tags: etymology

What is the Origin of the word *bedazzle*?

> The Audience was *bedazzled* by her charm.
>
> The glare of the Headlights *bedazzled* him.
>
> I will *bedazzle* my fans tonight.

According to the **[Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=bedazzle&searchmode=none)**, there is no specific origin of the word bedazzle other than it was first known to the English language in the late 1500s.

Comment: Can you please give me feedback if you are going to down vote this question?

Comment: Related: [How does the “be-” prefix change the words to which it is applied? How did it come about?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25951/how-does-the-be-prefix-change-the-words-to-which-it-is-applied-how-did-it-co/26019#26019)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The origin of ***[bedazzle](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bedazzle)*** is actually from the use of two existing terms, the prefix ***[be-](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/be-)*** and the verb  ***[dazzle](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dazzle)*** as an intensive form of dazzle, meaning *to dazzle thoroughly, confuse by dazzling.*:

Its early usage by Shakespeare probably contributed to its later popularity:

From:. The Taming Of The Shrew, ACT IV, SCENE V

> - 1596 Shakes. Tam. Shr. iv. v. 46 That haue bin so bedazled with the sunne.

Answer (score 4):

***Bedazzle*** means to dazzle intensely.

**The prefix *be..*** has a long usage in English and is of Teutonic origin. The OED carries a long article on the subject and supplies countless words which can be so prefixed: *behind, below, beneath, benorth, besouth, between, beyond* *befinger*, *becurse*, *befriend*, *bebotch*, *begirdle*,  the list is endless.

***Dazzle*** is a Middle English (15-16th) century word from the same root as ***daze***.

> **Old English be-**, weak or stressless form of the prep. and adv. bí (big), by n.1   The original Teutonic form was, as in Gothic, bi, with
>   short vowel, prob. cognate with second syllable of Greek ἀμϕί, Latin
>   ambi; in Old High German and early Old English, when it had the
>   stress, as a separate word, and in compounds formed with a noun, it
>   was lengthened to bī (bî, bí), while the stressless form, in compounds
>   formed with a vb. or indeclinable word, remained bi-; in later Old
>   English, as in Middle High German and modern German, the latter was
>   obscured to be- (also occasional in Old English as an unaccented form
>   of the preposition): cf. Old English bí-gęng practice, bi-gangan,
>   be-gangan, to practise.
>
> In early Middle English the etymological bi-,
>   by- regularly reappeared in compounds as the stressless form; but in
>   later times be- was finally restored. (On the other hand, be was used
>   by northern writers as the separate prep., as still in modern
>   Scottish.) In modern use, the unaccented prefix is always be-; the
>   accented form by- (sometimes spelt bye-) occurs in one or two words
>   descended from Old English, as ˈby-law, ˈby-word (Old English bí-lage,
>   bí-word), and in modern formations on the adv., as ˈby-gone, ˈby-name,
>   ˈby-play, ˈby-road, ˈby-stander.
>
> The original meaning was ‘about.’
>   In prepositions and adverbs this is weakened into a general expression
>   of position at or near, as in before (at, near, or towards the front),
>   behind, below, beneath, benorth, besouth, between, beyond. With verbs,
>   various senses of ‘about’ are often distinctly retained, as in
>   be-bind, be-come (= come about), be-delve, be-gird, be-set, be-stir.
>   In such as be-daub, be-spatter, be-stir, be-strew, the notion of ‘all
>   about, all round, over,’ or ‘throughout,’ naturally intensifies the
>   sense of the verb; whence, be- comes to be more or less a simple
>   intensive, as in be-muddle, be-crowd, be-grudge, be-break, or
>   specializes or renders figurative, as in befall (to fall as an
>   accident), be-come, be-get, be-gin, be-have, be-hold, be-lieve. In
>   other words the force of be- passes over to an object, and renders an
>   intransitive verb transitive, as in be-speak (speak about, for, or
>   to), be-flow (flow about), be-lie, be-moan, be-think, be-wail. Hence
>   it is used to form transitive vbs. on adjectives and substantives, as
>   in dim be-dim, fool be-fool, madam be-madam; also others, in which the
>   n. stands in an instrumental or other oblique relation, as be-night
>   ‘to overtake with night,’ be-guile, be-witch. Of these a special
>   section consists of verbs having a privative force, as Old English
>   belandian, behéafdian, to deprive of one's land, one's head: cf.
>   bereave v., and Old English benim-an to take away.
>
> Finally, be- is
>   prefixed with a force combining some of the preceding, to ppl. adjs.,
>   as in be-jewelled, be-daughtered.   Be- being still in some of its
>   senses (esp. 2,  6,  7   below) a living element, capable of being
>   prefixed wherever the sense requires it, the derivatives into which it
>   enters are practically unlimited in number. The more important,
>   including those that are in any way specialized, or that require
>   separate explanation, are treated in their alphabetical places as Main
>   Words. (In the case of Middle English words in bi-, by-, all that
>   survived long enough to have be- prefix   appear under this spelling;
>   a few that became obsolete at an early date are left under their only
>   extant form in bi- prefix, by- comb. form.) Those of less importance,
>   infrequent (often single) occurrence, and obvious composition, are
>   arranged under the following groups (in which, however, the senses
>   tend to overlap each other, so as to make the place of some of the
>   words ambiguous):—
>
> ***Daze***Etymology:  Middle English dase-n , < Old Norse *dasa, found in Icelandic in the reflexive dasa-sk  to become weary and exhausted,
>   e.g. from cold, Swedish dasa  intransitive to lie idle; compare
>   Icelandic dasi  a lazy fellow. Sense  3  was possibly the earliest in
>   English. No cognate words appear in the other Germanic languages.
>
> ***Dazzle***Forms:  ME–16 dasel(l, 15 dasill, dasyll, dazile, dassel(l, 15–16 dazel(l, dasle, 15–17 dazle, (16 daisle), 15–
>   dazzle.(Show Less)
>
> Etymology:  In 15–16th cent. dasel , dasle , frequentative and
>   diminutive of dase , daze v.  (especially in sense  2).(Show

Comment: That isn't the etymology though. There isn't a specifically known origin that I know of. According to your answer, dazzle doesn't have an origin. Just a frequent place of usage...Middle English. Here's a link

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=daze&searchmode=none

Answer (score 1):

Aside from your search results, [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bedazzled?s=t) claims that the word **bedazzled** originated between 1590-1600. [Merriam-Webster online](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bedazzle) claims the word's first known is from 1616. [Google N gram viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bedazzled&year_start=1590&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbedazzled%3B%2Cc0) notes popularity of the words usage in books beginning @1721 and continuing through modern day. And according to dictionary.com again the word "bedazzled" is derived from the word "[daze](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/daze)" and originates from Middle English, Danish, and old Norse usage circa 1275-1325.