# Is there a category name for verbs beginning with 'be-'? Is 'be-' a general prefix for words?

Tags: prefixes, archaicisms, be, category

I wonder about words like:

- Beseech
- Befallen
- Beholder (?)
- Bewitch
- Befool
- Befriend
- Befog

and so on...

Those words have always caught my attention, and I find them somewhat more sophisticated.

My questions are (no need to answer all at once) :

1. Is there a category for such words? For example, if I would be to search for words like 'greater', 'higher', 'more beautiful', I would find them under the **comparatives** category.
2. Can **'be-'** be used as a prefix in general? If so, how does it work?
3. How is the usage of such words viewed but a native English speaker? E.g. Archaic, poetic, prosaic, convoluted, just ok... ? I ask it because I've seen them to be used more in literature.

Comment: This might get you started: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/be-

Comment: [Interesting reading on etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=be-&allowed_in_frame=0): *Be- can also be privative (as in behead), causative, **or have just about any sense required**. The prefix **was productive 16c.-17c.** in forming useful words, many of which have not survived, such as bethwack "to thrash soundly" (1550s), betongue "to assail in speech, to scold" (1630s).*

Comment: We definitely need to bring back *bethwack*!

Comment: **betongue** ... let's bring this back.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "be-" prefix change the words to which it is applied? How did it come about?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25951/how-does-the-be-prefix-change-the-words-to-which-it-is-applied-how-did-it-co)

Comment: The OP's question is more ample, it is related to the indicated duplicate, but is not a duplicate. Leave open.

Comment: ... More ample? There are, as OP says, at least three questions here. Opening one not covered at the original question on be- (and perhaps answering it oneself) would be a good way to go.

Comment: I recall the use of the reflexive verb _beshit_ in _The Sotweed Factor_, a book which gloried in the awfulness of the US colonial environment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will be satisfied with Steve's quirky weblog post called *[Be-ing: The Bemusing, Busy Prefix be-](https://sblazak.wordpress.com/2010/05/28/be-ing-the-bemusing-prefix-be/#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CBe%2D%E2%80%9D%20as%20a%20prefix,%2C%20beyond%2C%20beloved%2C%20bereaved.)*. The use of this prefix is much more common than you think and does not apply to one particular category of words, to answer your first question.

Steve explains:

> “Be-” as a prefix goes back to Old English, apparent in such ancient-sounding words as ***betwixt***, ***betroth***, and ***bereft***.
>
> We see it in so *many common verbs* we use everyday: ***begin, behave, become, believe, befriend, belong***.
>
> And in *common prepositions and adjectives*: ***beneath, beside, below, between, beyond, beloved, bereaved***.

This prefix is strikingly versatile and productive. The same post explains:

> The prefix be- can act as an ***intensifier***, indicating something is thoroughly or excessively done, as in *bewitch, bewilder, bedazzle*. It can show ***a verb is affecting or causing*** something: *bedevil, bedim, befoul*.
> The prefix *be-* also expresses ***position***: b*eside, below, between, beneath, behind*. Or that something is ***covered all over or all around***: *bejeweled, bespattered, bewhiskered*. And *be-* can indicate ***creation***, *beget, begin, become*, or ***removal***, the end of existence, as in *begone,  bereave* (to take a loved one, especially in death), *bereft* (deprived of something) and, of course, *behead*. The multi-tasking prefix *be-* can ***turn an intransitive verb into a transitive one*** as in *bemoan and belie*. And *be-* can also ***turn nouns and adjectives into verbs***: *befriend, belittle, becalm*.

Consequently, the use of *be-* is not archaic in itself. Each word will be archaic or not according to its own itinerary. However, forming new words with this prefix is outdated now, as [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/be-) states:

> The prefix was productive 16c.-17c.

The same site gives an interesting detail:

> The Old English *be-* is the unstressed form of ***bi*** "***by***. The form has remained ***by-*** in stressed positions and in some more modern formations (***bylaw, bygones, bystander***).

Comment: There's also an old privative use, no longer productive: *behead, belimb, beland*.