# What does "betrun-cheoned" [betruncheoned] mean in Suttree by Cormac McCarthy

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

McCarthy's works are filled with obscure words, but this one is particularly strange, and prior to me posting this question, almost constitutes a [Googlewhack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Googlewhack).

I'm reading the Kindle edition and so it could even be a misprint.

The passage is this:

> The black wiped his eyes with one huge hand. Stories of the days and nights writ there, the scars, the teeth, the ear betrun-cheoned in some old fray that clung in a toadlike node to the side of his shaven head.

Comment: ... Betruncheoned. Very rare for 'walloped by a truncheon'. 'Truncheoned' itself is rare.

Comment: See also [cauliflower ear](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/cauliflower-ear) (or see wikipedia to actually see it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The word is betruncheoned. The  hyphen is misplaced (see comment by @GEdgar).

To truncheon something is to hit it with a [truncheon](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/truncheon) (a type of club used by the British police). Thus a betruncheoned ear is one that has been hit by a  truncheon.

[image]

---

**NOTE**

To understand why the word is "betruncheoned" and not simply "truncheoned", the following is relevant [How does the "be-" prefix change the words to which it is applied? How did it come about?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25951/how-does-the-be-prefix-change-the-words-to-which-it-is-applied-how-did-it-co)

Comment: ...and no ID number on the epaulette :(

Comment: @Weather Vane - Paid actor!

Comment: Probably the original hypenation was between lines, but when OCRd for Kindle was not combined to "betruncheoned"

Comment: Aha mystery solved :-)